# Reduce Single Array of Objects using two properties of an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a single array of objects and I would like to reduce it down to another array of objects based on two keys value pairs.

```
const original =
    [
        {
            key1: 'a',
            key2: 'AA',
            value: 1
        },
        {
            key1: 'a',
            key2: 'AA',
            anotherValue: 2
        },
        {
            key1: 'b',
            key2: 'BB',
            value: 1
        },
        {
            key1: 'a',
            key2: 'AA',
            yetAnother: 3
        },
        {
            key1: 'b',
            key2: 'BB',
            anotherValue: 4
        },
        {
            key1: 'c',
            key2: 'CC',
            value: 1
        }
    ];
```

Should be transformed into:

```
const result =
    [
        {
            key1: 'a',
            key2: 'AA',
            value: 1,
            anotherValue: 2,
            yetAnother: 3
        },
        {
            key1: 'b',
            key2: 'BB',
            value: 1,
            anotherValue: 4
        },
        {
            key1: 'c',
            key2: 'CC',
            value: 1
        },
    ];
```

Tired using map and reduce and even lodash. However, all my attempts were futile.

Comment: Your attempts would be far less _futile_ if you included them in your question

Comment: They were not even close. I'm relatively new to JS

Comment: How do you know you weren't close. The best idea when using StackOverflow is to include your attempts. Who knows, you might be very close or just have a typo and getting somebody else to check over your code can quickly pinpoint problems. You might even solve it yourself while trying to write out what you tried 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.reduce`, you can group the objects by `key1` and `key2` value pairs.
And the variable `groupBy` object values contain the result you want and you can generate the values only using `Object.values(groupBy)`.

```js
const original = [
  { key1: 'a', key2: 'AA', value: 1 },
  { key1: 'a', key2: 'AA', anotherValue: 2 },
  { key1: 'b', key2: 'BB', value: 1 },
  { key1: 'a', key2: 'AA', yetAnother: 3 },
  { key1: 'b', key2: 'BB', anotherValue: 4 },
  { key1: 'c', key2: 'CC', value: 1 }
];

const groupBy = original.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const { key1, key2, ...rest } = cur;
  const key = key1 + "_" + key2;
  acc[key] ? acc[key] = { ...acc[key], ...rest } : acc[key] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, build up a `Map` of entries, keyed by the combination of any `key*` properties while merging in the other properties.

Then you can convert the `Map` values into a new array

```js
const original = [{"key1":"a","key2":"AA","value":1},{"key1":"a","key2":"AA","anotherValue":2},{"key1":"b","key2":"BB","value":1},{"key1":"a","key2":"AA","yetAnother":3},{"key1":"b","key2":"BB","anotherValue":4},{"key1":"c","key2":"CC","value":1}]

const t1 = performance.now()

const result = [...original.reduce((map, obj) => {
  // create a key from all the "key*" properties
  const key = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => key.startsWith("key"))
    .sort()
    .map(key => obj[key]).join(":") // looks like "a:AA", "b:BB", etc
    
  // merge with previously found matches
  const entry = {
    ...(map.get(key) ?? {}),
    ...obj
  }
  
  // collect the merged object
  return map.set(key, entry)
}, new Map()).values()]

const t2 = performance.now()
console.info(result, `in ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```